# Get a Text from a Iframe with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get text from emails and save for send in webwhatsapp, but the text is in a iframe and returns a error when I try to get him

Thats the html code:

```
 <div id="mailContent" class="mail-content" style="height: 724px;">
 <div id="phishingLinkScanContent"></div> 
   <iframe id="bodyMailViewer"
 class="body-mail-viewer" style="height: 719px;"
 cd_frame_id_="18a0312a828e12092646c9a6b1ca58c4">
   #document 
   <html><head></head>
     <body>MetaTrader email test -&gt; cilabassa@terra.com.br<br><div id="ozoneAttachments"></div></body>
   </html> 
  </iframe> 
</div>
```

Thats my code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
texto = driver.find_element_by_id('bodyMailViewer').text
```

Thats the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="bodyMailViewer"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

Comment: Just do `print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First switch to the iframe and then locate the `body` tag under iframe and finally get the text from `body` tag. Try the below code.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
textInMail = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
```

Comment: but is find_element_by_tag_name